# CSS grid across device height without scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I have the following css:

```css
    body, html {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }
        
    .grid-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-rows: 30% 70%;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
      gap: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%
    }
    
    .grid-container button {
      padding: 10px;
    }
    
    .console {
      grid-column: span 2;
      color: #F12;
      background-color: #123;
      height: 98.5%
    }
```

with the following html:

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div class="grid-container">
      <button>Button 1</button>
      <button>Button 2</button>
      <div class="console">Textoutput here...</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The result I expect are 2 Buttons at the top using 30% of the space and the text div below using 70% of the space. With the example above I achieve this exactly behaviour

I tested this on Firefox and Edge with same result but what I do not understand:

```css
height: 98.5%
```

If I have the height of console on 100% I always presented with the scrollbar and content which uses more space than available. I further recognized that the `gap` seems to be the issue. So I decided to use `calc(100 - 10px)`, which worked.

And finally switched to a linux system and... it doesn't work.

I recognized that `grid-template-rows: 30vh 70vh;` worked better under linux but not with my workarounds for shrinking the height of `console`.

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use percentages in templates. They don't work well with gaps and you will have an overflow. Use `fr` instead. Then you can remove the height from console.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 3fr 7fr; /* it's 30fr 70fr but we can divide with 10 */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 10px;
  height: 100%
}

.grid-container button {
  padding: 10px;
}

.console {
  grid-column: span 2;
  color: #F12;
  background-color: #123;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <button>Button 2</button>
  <div class="console">Textoutput here...</div>
</div>
```